# ApplicationHealthIndicator removed from Springboot 2.7.2?

Tags: java, spring-boot, health-check

I currently updated my Spring boot version to 2.7.2 and after updating the version, I am having an error with the class org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.ApplicationHealthIndicator which says that it cannot be resolved to a type. I cannot find a documentation that it was removed. May I know if there is a new way to do a health check were it only returns status status UP?

Below is my code for it.

```
@Component
@Endpoint(id = "healthcheck")
public class HealthCheckEndpoint {

   @ReadOperation
   public Health health() {
      return new ApplicationHealthIndicator().health();
   }
}
```